# Detect whether a macro is void

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c99

I am trying to detect at compile time whether a macro is `void`. I know that the macro defines a type, but it can be any type (struct, pointer, array, function pointer, etc.) and I need to figure out whether this type is `void`. So far I have managed to make it work for integers and floating point types (below the macro under question is named `type`).

```
#define void +1
#define unsigned +0
#define signed +0
#define long +0
#define short +0
#define const +0
#define volatile +0

#if (type == void)
# warning "is void"
#else
# warning "is not void"
#endif

#undef volatile
#undef const
#undef short
#undef long
#undef signed
#undef unsigned
#undef void
```

The code is based on this description: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If

Is there a way to detect void at compile time in the general case (among all types)?

Comment: what is `type` and you really shouldn't define the tokens for the basic types.

Comment: Your `#define` s all cause undefined behaviour

Comment: What do you want to happen for `#define type const unsigned long int`?

Answer (score 3):

Defining a macro with a name that coincides with a reserved word is undefined behaviour.

Here's how to do this properly.

```
#if !defined(T)             // just for testing
#define T void
#endif

#define is_void   0
#define is_int    1
#define is_char   2
#define is_double 3

#define cat(x,y) cat2(x,y)
#define cat2(x,y) x##y

#if cat(is_, T) == is_void  // use the test
#error "type is void"       // or do something useful
#else
#error "type is not void"   // or do something useful
#endif
```

testing:

```
> gcc -E test.c -DT=void
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"
test.c:14:2: error: #error "type is void"
 #error "type is void"
  ^~~~~

> gcc -E test.c -DT=int
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"
test.c:16:2: error: #error "type is not void"
 #error "type is not void"
  ^~~~~
```

This can of course only work with tokens that are syntactically identifiers, so you cannot check for `int*` or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referring to the documentation of `gcc`, you can use its builtins:

```
#define IS_VOID(x) __builtin_types_compatible_p(x, void)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using C11 and static assert:

```
#define IS_VOID(x) _Static_assert(_Generic((x*)0,       \
                                           void*: 0,    \
                                           default: 1), \
                                  "void type " #x " detected")

...

#define T void

...

IS_VOID(T);
```

Compiler message on gcc:

> error: static assertion failed: "void type T detected"

The code uses `void*` instead of `void`, since `void` is an incomplete type and therefore can't exist inside the _Generic expression.